# Excel VBA Compile Error: Type Mismatch, but line above is similar without error

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a Type Mismatch error where .Row is highlighted and I cannot figure out why this is happening. I commented the line that has the error. The line of code above this is similar but not generating the error message. These a ranges that vary in size from day to day. I am not sure if the problem is with the declaration or the the range itself. I tried adding a "+1+ and a "-1" after .Row, but I received the same error message. Any help is appreciated.

```
    Sub DDS_SUMIFS()
    '
    ' DDS_SUMIFS Macro
    '
    
    '
       ' ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=SUMIFS('Raw Data - DS'!R2C6:R14664C6,'Raw Data - DS'!R2C1:R14664C1,'Dock Door Status'!RC5,'Raw Data - DS'!R2C8:R14664C8,'Dock Door Status'!R32C)"
       ' ActiveCell.Select
        'Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:C1"), Type:= _
            xlFillDefault
       ' ActiveCell.Range("A1:C1").Select
        'Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:C10"), Type:= _
            xlFillDefault
        'ActiveCell.Range("A1:C10").Select
        'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Activate
        
    Dim DSQTY As Range
Dim NSQTY As Long
Dim DSDestWH, NSDestWH, DSWorkPool, NSWorkPool As Range
Dim RDDS, RDNS As Worksheet
Dim ABQ1, BFI4, CLE2, DEN3, DEN4, GEG1, LIT1, ORD5, ORF3, PAE2, PCW1, PDX9, SLC1, SMF1 As String

Set RDDS = Sheets("Raw Data - DS")
Set RDNS = Sheets("Raw Data - NS")

Set DSQTY = RDDS.Range("F2").End(xlUp).Row
Set NSQTY = RDNS.Range("F2").End(xlUp).Row    '<----- Error: Object Required (NSQTY = is highlighted)
    
    Set DSDestWH = RDDS.Range("A2").End(xlUp).Row
    Set NSDestWH = RDNS.Range("A2").End(xlUp).Row
    Set DSWorkPool = RDDS.Range("F2").End(xlUp).Row
    Set NSWorkPool = RDNS.Range("F2").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ABQ1 = "ABQ1"
    BFI4 = "BFI4"
    CLE2 = "CLE2"
    DEN3 = "DEN3"
    DEN4 = "DEN4"
    GEG1 = "GEG1"
    LIT1 = "LIT1"
    ORD5 = "ORD5"
    ORF3 = "ORF3"
    PAE2 = "PAE2"
    PCW1 = "PCW1"
    PDX9 = "PDX9"
    SLC1 = "SLC1"
    SMF1 = "SMF1"
    
    ' PNYP Column
    
    Range("H33") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, ABQ1, DSWorkPool, "PNYP")
    Range("H34") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, BFI4, DSWorkPool, "PNYP")
    Range("H35") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, CLE2, DSWorkPool, "PNYP")
    Range("H36") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, DEN3, DSWorkPool, "PNYP")
    Range("H37") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, DEN4, DSWorkPool, "PNYP")
    Range("H38") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, GEG1, DSWorkPool, "PNYP")
    Range("H39") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, LIT1, DSWorkPool, "PNYP")
    Range("H40") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, ORD5, DSWorkPool, "PNYP")
    Range("H41") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, ORF3, DSWorkPool, "PNYP")
    Range("H42") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, PAE2, DSWorkPool, "PNYP")
    Range("H43") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(NSQTY, NSDestWH, PCW1, NSWorkPool, "PNYP")
    Range("H44") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(NSQTY, NSDestWH, PDX9, NSWorkPool, "PNYP")
    Range("H45") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(NSQTY, NSDestWH, SLC1, NSWorkPool, "PNYP")
    Range("H46") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(NSQTY, NSDestWH, SMF1, NSWorkPool, "PNYP")
    
    ' PP Column
    
    Range("H33") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, ABQ1, DSWorkPool, "PP")
    Range("H34") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, BFI4, DSWorkPool, "PP")
    Range("H35") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, CLE2, DSWorkPool, "PP")
    Range("H36") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, DEN3, DSWorkPool, "PP")
    Range("H37") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, DEN4, DSWorkPool, "PP")
    Range("H38") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, GEG1, DSWorkPool, "PP")
    Range("H39") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, LIT1, DSWorkPool, "PP")
    Range("H40") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, ORD5, DSWorkPool, "PP")
    Range("H41") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, ORF3, DSWorkPool, "PP")
    Range("H42") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, PAE2, DSWorkPool, "PP")
    Range("H43") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(NSQTY, NSDestWH, PCW1, NSWorkPool, "PP")
    Range("H44") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(NSQTY, NSDestWH, PDX9, NSWorkPool, "PP")
    Range("H45") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(NSQTY, NSDestWH, SLC1, NSWorkPool, "PP")
    Range("H46") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(NSQTY, NSDestWH, SMF1, NSWorkPool, "PP")
    
    ' LD Column
    
    Range("H33") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, ABQ1, DSWorkPool, "LD")
    Range("H34") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, BFI4, DSWorkPool, "LD")
    Range("H35") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, CLE2, DSWorkPool, "LD")
    Range("H36") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, DEN3, DSWorkPool, "LD")
    Range("H37") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, DEN4, DSWorkPool, "LD")
    Range("H38") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, GEG1, DSWorkPool, "LD")
    Range("H39") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, LIT1, DSWorkPool, "LD")
    Range("H40") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, ORD5, DSWorkPool, "LD")
    Range("H41") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, ORF3, DSWorkPool, "LD")
    Range("H42") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DSQTY, DSDestWH, PAE2, DSWorkPool, "LD")
    Range("H43") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(NSQTY, NSDestWH, PCW1, NSWorkPool, "LD")
    Range("H44") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(NSQTY, NSDestWH, PDX9, NSWorkPool, "LD")
    Range("H45") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(NSQTY, NSDestWH, SLC1, NSWorkPool, "LD")
    Range("H46") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(NSQTY, NSDestWH, SMF1, NSWorkPool, "LD")
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: `DSQTY` is declared `As Variant`, `NSQTY` is declared `As Range`. `.Row` returns a `Long`. You cannot save a `Long` in a `Range`, you can in a `Variant`. Although not with `Set`, so you should be having a (different) error on the previous line too. And on all the other lines where you save a `.Row` to what you believe to be a `Range`, apparently under impression that it returns the actual row of cells in question.

Comment: Change `NSQTY As Range` to `Dim NSQTY As Long`

Comment: Made the suggested changes and received an Object Required error (See edit in post)

Comment: If you calculate `Row` numbers variable should be of type `Long`. And with `Long` type don't use `Set`.

Comment: I am trying to make DSQTY and NSQTY the SUMRANGES of a SUMIFS formula. The sumranges will vary in length each day and are on two different worksheets. How do I get this to sum that range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim DSQTY As Range, NSQTY As Range
Dim DSDestWH As Range, NSDestWH As Range
Dim DSWorkPool As Range, NSWorkPool As Range
Dim RDDS As Worksheet, RDNS As Worksheet
' Each variable must be declared separately unless they are of type Variant
' ... next lines of your code
With RDDS
    Set DSQTY = .Range("F2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
    Set DSDestWH = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Set DSWorkPool = .Range("F2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
End With

With RDNS
    Set NSQTY = .Range("F2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
    Set NSDestWH = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Set NSWorkPool = .Range("F2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
End With

' ... next lines of your code
```

Are you sure that `DSQTY` and `DSWorkPool` are in the same column?
And also `NSQTY` and `NSWorkPool`?

Comment: I had made some formatting changes to the two worksheets and forgot to update the code. DSWorkPool and NSWorkPool are column H, not F. I will try your suggestions and update shortly. Thanks.

Comment: I had to add a couple more lines to your code above and IT WORKED!! Thank you SOOOO MUCH! Tha code i added was 'Set RDDS = Sheets("Raw Data - DS")' and 'RDNS = Sheets("Raw Data - NS")'.